# Use index of maximum value on a defined axis

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract the values of an array "B" at the same index of the maximum of each line of the matrix "A". to find the index I use the numpy function "numpy.argmax" like this:

```
>>> A=numpy.asarray([[0,1,6],[3,2,4]]);A
array([[0, 1, 6],
       [3, 2, 4]])
>>> argA=numpy.argmax(A,axis=1);argA
array([2, 2])
```

The problem is that I don't know how to use "argA" to extract the values in the array "B"

Answer (score 4):

Each entry in `argA` corresponds to the index position of a maximum value within a corresponding row. The rows are not explicit (due to using `axis=1`), but correspond to the index for each entry. So you need to add them in to get at the elements you are after.

```
>>> A[[0,1], argA]
array([6, 4])
```

So:

```
>>> B
array([[ 9,  8,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5]])
>>> B[[0,1], argA] = 84,89
>>> B
array([[ 9,  8, 84],
       [ 3,  4, 89]])
```

to generalise use:

```
>>> B[np.arange(A.shape[0]),argA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array directly as an index - this is actually as simple as:

```
B[:, arga]
```

eg:

```
>>> A[:,argA]
array([[6, 6],
       [4, 4]])
```

Comment: I have already try it but it doesn't work:
B=numpy.arange(6);B.shape=(2,-1);B
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> B[argA]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index (2) out of range (0<=index<1) in dimension 0

Comment: @loco -- did you forget the ','?  (I did).  -- e.g. `B[:,argA]` instead of `B[:argA]`

Comment: @loco note that you have to get it along the right axis - `B[argA]` tries to use the values of `argA` along axis 0, which gives that error. `B[:, argA]` tells it to use axis 1 instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may appear a little inefficient, but you could use:

```
A.take(argA, axis=1).diagonal()
```

Instead of `A.take` you can use `A[:, argA]` but `take` is more explicit about the axis.

You could use `ravel_multi_index` to convert to flat indices:

```
A.take(np.ravel_multi_index((np.arange(len(argA)), argA), A.shape))
```